# Spacemacs Font Corrupted

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

Today, when I opened Spacemacs, it becomes like this:
[Spacemacs's font become squares](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcD6H.png)

I am not sure what happened since I have not using emacs for a long time, it was updating when I open it, so I assume it is not a out of date issue. I also try to reinstall, but it still remain the same bad result.

Wish someone good at Spacemacs can give me a hint.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .spacemacs file, look for **dotspacemacs-default-font**.  If you haven't changed it already for some reason, it should be set to "Source Code Pro" (along with size, weight, width, etc.).  If you've got a fixed width font that you know is installed on your system, you can specify it here.  Alternatively, you can explicitly install Source Code Pro on your system.  After either of those steps, restart emacs and see if text is displaying.